# MongoDB lookup get referenced object id and advice for reference

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I'm using PyMongo and MongoDB 4.0.1. For the example I'll call my collections User and Car. So my user can get only one car (One to One relationship)

```
User
----
_id : ObjectId("2b2543b24713ea82ce3ae21f")
Firstname : John
Lastname : Doe
Car : ObjectId("5b854bb806a77a06ce321f1f")

Car
----
_id : ObjectId("5b854bb806a77a06ce321f1f")
Model : Tesla Motor
```

When I do this query :

```
db.user.aggregate(
  {$unwind: "$car"},
  {$lookup: {
    from:"car",
    localField: "car",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "car"
   }}
)
```

the output show me that car property will be an array of cars with one object...

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("2b2543b24713ea82ce3ae21f"), 
  "firstname" : "John", 
  "lastname" : "Doe" , 
  "car" : [ { 
      "_id" : ObjectId("5b854bb806a77a06ce321f1f"), 
      "model" : "Tesla Motor"
   }] 
}
```

It's possible to get just one object and not an array ?

Another question about references. Lot of different Users can get the same car. It is good in No SQL database to reference the object id or it's better to create all car fields in the User collection ? Because I have to update all different data. For example if there is a change on the Car I think it's easier to update just one document in the Car collection than update 50 rows in the user collection.

Do you think I'm right ?

Comment: you can `$unwind` the `car` array or use `$arrayElemAt` aggregation

Comment: But I'm using $unwind. I did wrong ?

Comment: You are using it in first stage... Move it to second stage after `$lookup`

Comment: Oh it's pretty. Why the place is so important ?

Comment: you can learn about aggregation pipeline here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you have an advice for my second question ?

Comment: Creating 50 rows is not a good approach... I would advise you to go with your first option of referencing because now join is easily possible with the `$lookup` aggregation

Comment: Ok. So there is no problem about the performance ? Because I often heard with No SQL Database, relationships will render the query slower

Comment: indexing will surely resolve your problem here...

Comment: Ok so thank you very much man !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the  [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) after the [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage

```
db.user.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "car",
    "localField": "car",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "car"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$car" }
])
```